# How to enable/install the php fileinfo module for php 7.2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, nginx

I am running a nginx Server on ubuntu of which i am trying to install moodle. But I cant procédé with the setup because it needs the php fileinfo module enabled/or/instald. To be able to procédé with the instal of moodle.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu / Debian fileinfo is supposedly installed and enabled by default,
so I find your problem a bit puzzling.

I suggest to check if in the file `php.ini` you have  the following line, and if not
then add it :

```
extension=fileinfo.so
```

If the file is commented out, just delete the `;` at the beginning of the line.

If you still have a problem, check if you have the shared library `fileinfo.so`
in the `ext` folder of PHP.

Comment: ive checkt the exstension folder.and  the php.ini   it seems to be added . but its not loading for some reason - i am using php-fpm v 7.2

Comment: Something may be wrong with fileinfo.so. My guess would be a missing dependency. For checking see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120015/17660).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5127838/165358